# Get an element by a substring of its value in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this `content = ['C:\User\Folder\a.txt', 'C:\User\Folder\big_a.txt', 'C:\User\Folder\small_a.txt']` in which every item is unique, I can't have for example two `C:\User\Folder\small_a.txt`s, of course. 
 Now I want to get the item that matches the string `big`. 
 What I'm doing is

```
for file in content:
    if 'big' in file:
        path = file
        break
```

And it works. 
 
 What I ask you is: there's a different way to do that? Maybe more efficient or something in one line? 
 Just curiosity

Comment: Are you sure only one item will contain `big` as a substring?

Comment: You maybe want to change it to `if 'big' in file.split('/')[-1]`, what if the path contains `big`?

Comment: have a look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-filter-list-of-strings-based-on-the-substring-list/

Comment: @chris yes, just one file.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse the path does not contain `big`. Just focus on the file name not the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This basically does the same of your code:

```
path = next(file for file in content if "big" in file)
```

Comment: Ah, nice idea with `next`. +1

Comment: Or also, `file = [i for i in content if "big" in i][0]`

Comment: @User generating an entire list is always *slower*. Instead, you should make use of generators.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco ah because `next()` uses generator. Nice solution.

Comment: Caveat: this raises a `StopIteration` exception if no items match “big”. If this is a possibility, then a `try:` block will be needed, or a default value should be given to `next`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to do the same task in fewer lines, but it will not be the most optimal since it will not contain the `break` statement. Regardless of whichever way you chose to do (list-comprehension vs for) this will be an `O(n)` operation.

```py
content = ["a.txt", "big_a.txt", "small_a.txt"]
file = next(i for i in content if "big" in i)

print(file) #> big_a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about efficiency, but this is definitely beautiful to read and write

```
path = [file for file in  content if 'big' in file]
```

Comment: `path` should be a string, not a list!

Comment: @RiccardoBucco yes, you're right. I need a string result.